# build the chained select using json

Tags: javascript, json, select

I want to build the chainded select element in my page,so I use the json to save the data.

The data:

```
    var data=[{"name":"Java Language","value":"java","options":[
            {"name":"Thinking In Java","value":"tinjava"},
            {"name":"Thinking in Pattern","value":"tininpat"},
            {"name":"The Core Java","value":"core_java"}
        ]},
        {"name":"Ruby Language","value":"ruby","options":[
            {"name":"Programming Ruby","value":"p_ruby"},
            {"name":"The Ruby Guide","value":"ruby_guide"}
        ]},
        {"name":"The JavaScript","value":"js","options":[
            {"name":"Jquery In Action","value":"jquery"},
            {"name":"Prototype","value":"prototype"},
            {"name":"The Core Javascript","value":"core_js"}
        ]}];
```

This is the code to build the element:

```
        var par_select=document.getElementById("par");
        var chd_select=document.getElementById("chd");
        //init the parenet select
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            var fdata=data[i];
            var opt=document.createElement("option");
            opt.text=fdata.name;
            opt.value=fdata.value;
            par_select.appendChild(opt);
        }

        //bind change event to the par_select
        par_select.onchange=function(e){
            //clear the data in the child select
            chd_select.innerHTML="";
            var val=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
            var sel_data;
            //find the selected object
                            //////////   QUESTION  !!!!///////////////////
            for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                if(data[i].value==val){
                    sel_data=data[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(sel_data){
                var chd_options=sel_data.options;
                for(var i=0;i<chd_options.length;i++){
                    var opt=document.createElement("option");
                    opt.text=chd_options[i].name;
                    opt.value=chd_options[i].value;
                    chd_select.appendChild(opt);
                }
            }
        }

        //trigger the change event to the par_select
        par_select.onchange();
```

I have make it work.

But I wonder if there is any way to make it fast?

Since in my implemention,when the first select changed,I have to iterator the json data to find the right object,then change the seconde select accordingly.

It does not matter if the data have a small number of items.

But In my app,the items will more than 40.

That's to say:

```
(data.length>40)==true;
```

So I wonder if there are any good suggestion to improve it?

A full example can be found here:

http://jsfiddle.net/jhS5w/

BTW,I can not use any javascript libray except prototype 1.4

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if it's much faster as I did absolutely no benchmarking, but the general idea is the reduce the number of loops and the number of actions per loop and reduce the number of DOM actions, preferably to 1, I reduced it to 2 using documentFragment:
http://jsfiddle.net/jhS5w/7/